# Make auto install Android app from play market from my application for android mobile

Tags: android, download, google-play

I need to do following thing from my android application please give me idea to make it possible.

1.I known package name to install which is on play google market.
now when i execute code it should start that Application to download in my android mobile.

Same thing is done by Play google for example.

In  web site of google play if i select facebook to install it will start download in my android mobile So again my question is how i can achieve to direct start download application from Google play by my installed android application.

Finally what i have found to make install android app from developer site is below.

[Developer distribution App Intent](http://developer.android.com/distribute/googleplay/promote/linking.html) .
But in that code user have to accept install and term button to start real download Application and i don't want to

Thanks for any help.

Comment: The thing you are trying to achieve has already been viewed as a _security issue_. The _advantage or feature_ you assume to provide has huge security implications.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question, what you want is your app to be a replacement of the google play app in that it can download directly from google play store and without asking the user for permission. This is not possible. It's a security feature that android has to ask the phone user whether or not it's okay to download a certain app. Without this it would be possible to install malicious apps without the user knowing.

Comment: Actually Google Play can able to download Application remotely in android mobile when user select app from Brower by Google Login.

Comment: yes but that is google play downloading the app, android trusts and knows that that is a request made by the owner of the account.